# Why is performance Counter Not Working At all

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, performancecounter

For some reason, my performance counter doesn't work. I saw this performance counter working on other people's laptop & desktop, but not mine.
It doesn't have a list to let me choose, and other people do not have this problem at all. Even though I catch it from server manager I guess, and put it on to the form, it is still showing "System.Diagnostic.PerformanceCounter" Which is very annoying at all.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;

namespace MonitorC
{
public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    //PerformanceCounter perfCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    //PerformanceCounter perfRAMCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    //PerformanceCounter perfSysCounter = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CPUusage.Text = performanceCounter1.ToString();
        RAMusage.Text = performanceCounter2.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();

    }
}
}
```

**1st image:**

[image]

**2nd image:**

[image]

**3rd image:**

[image]

**Code I have:**

[image]

Comment: please copy paste your code here as it is no use to us if they are images

Comment: Ok I did, if you need the whole sln, I can give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add call to `NextSample` to get raw value or `NextValue` to get calculated value. Like this:

```
performaceCounter1.NextValue().ToString();
```